# Headphone audio only works after returning from suspend

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, drivers

I've been having this problem for more than a month now and it's bugging me. I have an K45A Asus notebook dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04. This problem only happens in Windows:

Every time i turn on the computer, my only audio output device that works is the internal ones and as long as i don't plug in my headphones in the front panel jack all is fine.

There is no sound coming from the headphones if i plug them. I can see that Realtek software correctly recognizes that it was inserted, but no sound. Headphones only have sound *after* returning from sleep/suspend mode (by closing the lid or via UI).

I already tried to no avail:

- Reinstall drivers several times.
- Checking playback devices: the only that appears is the default. There are no hidden sources.
- Checked Realtek output sources in software driver.

All working flawlessly in Ubuntu.

I am suspecting this is a power scheme issue.
Did anyone have similar problem and have any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went to Realtek website, got latest drivers from there and made a clean reinstall, i.e removed old drivers with Revo Uninstaller cleaning all remains and installed new ones.

Went to Power Options in control panel, clicked Alter configs. of Scheme and restored to defaults.

After that my headphones are working properly as soon as i turn.